# seach and replace the value inside curely braces

Tags: perl

I want to search the value between curly braces for each line in a file
and replace the corresponding value with 
0x0 (For e.g. 1-->0x01,7-->0x07)

Initially i was checking with regex (/{(.*?)}/) this regex able to search all the value inside {} braces.
input Data:

```
 abc_def  xxxx { 0} xxx
 my_new_type new{ 0}    my_new_type 
 c++_programming    MY_NPYR{ 1} c++_programming 
 cprogramming   ABCCDDDDRRRRTTTT { 2}   cprogramming    
 perlbook   NEW{ 7} xxxxx
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file  = 'input.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file  or die "Couldn't open input file: $!";
while (<$fh>) 
{

if (/{(.0?)}/)
{
 s/0/0x00/;             
}
elsif (/{(.1?)}/)
{
s/1/0x01/;            
}
elsif (/{(.2?)}/)
{
 s/2/0x02/;             
}
elsif (/{(.7?)}/)
{
 s/7/0x07/;            
}

}
```

any help with explanation would be grateful.

Comment: There's no `DATA` in your code.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the regex `/{(.0?)}/`? What is each part meant to do?

Comment: `s/\{ (\d+)\}/sprintf('{ %#x}', $1)/ge`

Comment: @MattJacob `%#x` doesn't work for 0. You need `0x%x`.

Comment: @melpomene It was a 90% solution ;-)

Comment: Initially i was checking with regex (/{(.*?)}/) this regex able to search all the value inside {} braces but in my case i wanted to go with each value. if the line contain {3} i do not need search and replacement.

Comment: output should be {0x00,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x07}

Comment: OK, so change the format string to `0x%02x`. You could at least read the docs for [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) on your own...

Comment: @MattJacob not working for me please check

Comment: Please check what?

Comment: @MattJacob Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as `script.pl` and invoke it as `$ perl script.pl input.txt`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    s/\{ (\d+)\}/sprintf('{ 0x%02x}', $1)/ge;
    print;
}
```

The `e` [regex modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) evaluates the right-hand side as an expression.

Comment: Preserve existing spaces (without requiring them): `s/\{\s*\K(\d+)(?=\s*\})/ sprintf('0x%02x', $1) /ge`